# How to prevent Blender to overheat my computer while rendering?

Tags: rendering

How do I prevent Blender to overheat my computer while i'm rendering I hight resolution image?

I use a MacBook Air OS X Yosemite

Proccesor: 1,4 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: Blender will use your computer hardware to render, I don't believe the resolution has anything to do with heating your hardware, except that it will take longer, so your processor will be working for longer. This question is about hardware not about Blender.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. I'll delete this question

Comment: I prop the back of my laptop up to allow more airflow. Helps slightly. There are also products like https://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=computer+cooling+fan+pad&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=97079869717&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14870770102599696655&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_65u986g5h9_b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For complex rendering in general, reducing the "threads" can help. (Under performance tab in render)
The computer will auto-calculate it, but you can set it lower than the auto value through the "fixed" option. The render will be slower, but it will be less intense and cause less heating/crashes.

[image]

Comment: My render properties does not have a performance tab. How do you get there please?