# Is there a way I can make render times longer to avoid overheating?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Whenever I render a picture above 16 samplings with *Cycles*, *my laptop crashes in 5-20 seconds.*

**Is there a way I can manually make the render time longer while not affecting the quality of the render,** so it doesn't get my laptop so hot it self-crashes to not melt itself? (I'm willing to use Add-Ons and, if there is a denoiser that could make a render with 16 samplings look like a render with 128 or 64 samplings that's okay for me as well.)

I live in a very poor country and can't afford a decent PC/laptop. Maximum I can afford is something below 50$ (Which would hurt my wallet quite a lot).

Comment: Replace ur laptop. 16 sample overheat is like EN12-82 computational power.

Comment: I have a Lenovo laptop, $200 from a couple years ago, and it rendered cycles fairly slowly but not THAT bad. And Lenovo is currently like the cheapster brand that isn’t outright horrible.

Comment: Well I mean, I live in a very poor country and can't afford anything better than this.

Comment: The best thing I could buy right now is a 10-50$ laptop (If something like that even exists).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55868/how-to-prevent-blender-to-overheat-my-computer-while-rendering https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/how-to-stop-blender-from-making-the-cpu-overheat

Comment: None of the answers really solves the root of the problem. Ideally you should (carefully) try blowing out as much dust from the laptop if you can since it shouldn't really be overheating in the first place. You could also try a laptop cooling pad which would be relatively cheap. At any rate, just limiting the number of threads, particularly on a single/dual core laptop may not be a great help. On both Windows and Linux it is possible to set a CPU governor/power profile to restrict the CPU from running at full power at the cost of speed which would solve the problem in other applications too

Comment: @James Answers should go in the _Answers_ section.

Comment: @pipe: The OP hasn't even mentioned which OS they are using or what kind of CPU they have, meaning there is not enough information to give a detailed answer. I suspect it might also be considered off-topic by some

Comment: You may be able to fiddle with your Power settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926390/how-can-i-deliberately-slow-windows#comment64586762_926444

Comment: Hi michael. Where do you live and what laptop (CPU/RAM) do you currently have?

Comment: Just to check. Is your laptop full of dust? A cheap laptop is expected to be slow, but not to overheat. If it's old simply cleaning the dust out of the fans may help reduce overheating

Comment: @James My laptop isn't dusty at all and I do have a cooling pad I bought about 5 years ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a related [SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process).

In Blender, you can lower the number of threads by going to *Render Properties* -> *Performance*.

[image]

Change from auto-detect and lower the number of threads.

I lowered mine to 2 and started a CPU render and it does appear to split the compute load pretty evenly among the processor cores, so one part of the chip won't necessarily be hotter than the other and it should prevent an overheat.

[image]

(This PC runs pretty hot.) :)

It's also worth quickly noting that denoising is a processor intensive task in itself, so it may not be a solution.

Answer (score 9):

Additional to the other answers, you've also asked for a denoiser - I don't know if you've already tried the *Denoise* node in the *Compositor*, it's quite good. Usually you're supposed to turn on *View Layer Properties* > *Passes* > *Denoising Data* with it, but testing this I couldn't see much of a difference. So to use it, go to the *Compositor*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to *Add* > *Filter* > *Denoise* and plug it between *Render Layers* and *Composite*.

Here an example image with node setup:
[image]

Comment: Curious, is this a photo or a render?

Comment: @HashimAziz It's a render... that's why the image on the left is noisy without the _Denoise Node_.

Answer (score 8):

Besides Allen's answer, which is correct, you could also try to lower down memory consumption (which is called "memory cache limit") in the blender references.

[image]

Another try worth might be to denoise in a 2nd step...

Answer (score 4):

If there's ever a non-built-in way to do this (luckly Blender has it), you can change the CPU affinity in Task Manager details view.

[image: Affinity context menu]

[image: Affinity dialog]

Threads auto detected in Blender: 16

[image: Threads autodetected in Blender]

Cores actually used:

[image: Cores actually used]

Also, if overheating is caused by Turbo Boost feature, you can prevent that by setting the maximum CPU usage to 99% in the power options.

[image: Prevent turbo boost]