# Stains on white walls_interior render_denoiser

Tags: denoise, noise-reduction

I am trying to render an interior image but I have problems with the white walls. As shown in the image attached there are "stains" caused I think by the DENOISER. (I guess so because of a tutorial I have seen on youtube). The render is running on my Macbook pro mid 2014, and the rendering settings are the ones of the screenshot attached. I don't need any high resolution image but just uniform surfaces for a quick preview.
As lighting: The scene has an area light in front of the window hole as "portal" and an hdr image attached.
The walls have no material assigned, and even assigning materials things don't change.

Is there any way to correct this simple mistake? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

[image: render]

[image: settings]

Comment: Hi, can you please share your file?

Comment: sure, here it is: https://we.tl/t-sNCF7BCYw3

Comment: @AllenSimpson. Thank you for the link. I guess it is a common denoising problem, there is an image that looks exaclty as the one I posted. Even though the post doesn't give a real solution to that particular case, it seems I have good company. I wonder if the denoiser will be improved to answer such a simple task as rendering white walls smoothly!

Comment: More samples, it'll still be faster than waiting for the image to resolve normally.  I added an answer there for the intel denoiser in the compositor, it may give a better result than the render denoise checkbox.

Comment: @AllenSimpson. Thank you, I added more samples and the image it's slowly improving. I wished there was a less 'overheating' solution but I will do that.

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/221727/is-there-a-way-i-can-make-render-times-longer-to-avoid-overheating